Creating tar file from the output file names from for loop in shell script
I want to iterate through all the folders present in path3 and then get length number of files inside each of them at depth of 1 and make a single tar from them, I am trying something like this:
  path3=A/B/C

  if [$length != 0 ];then
    for dir in $(find "$path3" -type d)
     do
      find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f | tail -$length
     done
    xargs tar cvfz mpe-tar/$i/part_2.tgz
  fi

But tar is not getting created , how to pass the output from for loop to xargs and get the tar?
I am expecting single tar file containing length number of files at depth 1 from each folders in path3.

what is $i? find produces unsorted output. If there are more than $length files, which should be added to the tar file?

Aside from the fact that you never assign a value to i, you don't seem to feed anything into the stdin of xargs. Also, I would expect that [$length != 0 ] gives you an error message.

You can modify your code like this:
path3="A/B/C"
length=5  # Adjust the length as needed

if [ "$length" -ne 0 ]; then
  # Collect the files into a temporary list
  file_list=$(mktemp)

  for dir in $(find "$path3" -type d); do
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | tail -n "$length" >> "$file_list"
  done

  # Create the tar file using the collected list of files
  tar cvfz "mpe-tar/part_2.tgz" -T "$file_list"

  # Remove the temporary list
  rm "$file_list"
fi


Thanks @liaifat85 but is there a way that without creating list , can I pass output of for loop to xargs

You can try to pass the output of the for loop directly to xargs without creating an intermediate list file. You can try this by piping the output of the for loop commands to xargs.

You could for ... find "$dir" -maxdepth ... done | tar cvfz "mpe-tar/part_2.tgz" -T - !!

@liaifat85 but if I iterate through for loop each time won't tar file will get overridden each time?

Or better: for dir ... ; do find ... -type f -print0 ;done | tar -cvfz "mpe-tar/part_2.tgz" --null -T -

@F.Hauri - Give Up GitHub What is the use of -T here?
Also I tried this:
if [$length != 0 ];then
for dir in $(find "$path3" -type d)
do
find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tail -$length
done | tar cvfz mpe-tar/$i/part_2.tgz --null -T -
fi
but getting
tar: Failed to open 'mpe-tar/xyz/part_2.tgz'

Oh sorry use tail -z -n $length instead!! About your last question:  tar -T - tell tar to take file list from standard input. -print0 in find, -z in tail and --null in tar command use null tarminated string instead of space separated string in order to be able to handle correctly files names that contain spaces or special characters.

But find don't sort his ouptut, so find | tail will arbitrary list only $length files. I don't understand what you're trying to do, but this seem not reliable.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGithub,
if [$length != 0 ];then
for dir in $(find "$path3" -type d)
do
find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tail -z -n $length
done | tar cvfz mpe-tar/$i/part_2.tgz --null -T -
fi
now I am getting: tar: Failed to open 'mpe-tar/xyz/part_2.tgz'
tail: invalid option -- z

Because of -f flag of tar MUST be followed by filename! Try: tar -zcvf "mpe-tar/part_2.tgz" instead!  Alternatively try this: path3="A/B/C" length=5;if ((length));then while read -rd '' dir;do find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tail -zn $length ;done < <(find "$path3" -type d -print0) | tar -zcvf "mpe-tar/part_2.tgz" --null -T -;fi

for dir in $(find "$path3" -type d); do is an antipattern - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Input_source_selection
